# Will create an international mirror site hurt my SEO

Tags: seo, domains, duplicate-content, internationalization

I was approached by someone from India looking to copy parts of my website content in India under a **new domain name** (which would be the same as mine, but ending in `.in`)

The `.in` website would list the same products and product descriptions, and would still be in English, but the target audience would be set to India in Google Webmaster tools.

Is there any chance that this could hurt the SEO for my US-based website?

Comment: Why would someone want to do this?? What is the pay-off for this other individual to do this? I also fear that you would be giving up WAY too much control and will easily regret making an agreement such as this.

Comment: Basically they want to emulate my business model in India.. I have business concerns as well, but I am trying to separate my concerns and get information about SEO for now.

Comment: Any visitors that you currently get from India would end up going to their `.in` site.   Is that a success or an SEO problem for you?

Comment: There could also be duplicate content issues, branding issues, confusion, etc. Not advisable from where I stand. Especially from a search perspective. You would be competing with yourself. If they want your business, then they can buy it or start one of their own. But they damned well better not register your domain name with a .in ccTLD. I would jump and protect your interests and register that domain if you can. You can always assign it to the other party if you chose to later.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller, not necessarily an issue for me.. I'm more worried about it having a negative impact on my SEO for my US-based website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If People search about your business from India probably Google will **display** search from the `.in` website.

Any visitors that you currently get from India would end up going to their **`.in`** site.

If the `.in` website gains popularity it may appear more than your **US** website in search results.

You should act fast and  report that .in website to Google by using

https://support.google.com/legal/troubleshooter/1114905

and

https://lumendatabase.org/